# 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic'' in IIS log file

Tags: python, iis, pip, web-config, uvicorn

I cant run my python project in IIS
It works perfect in local running, so I guess it have all packages and libraries needed,
but in IIS it looks like something missing

Python project from GIT, after installing

```
>pip install -r requirements.txt
>pip install -r requirements-server.txt
```

the app running successfuly in python (VScode) and also with uvicorn:

```
>uvicorn server:app --reload
```

it works perfect on browsing to: http://127.0.0.1:8000

Now I configure the folder as website in IIS
But then the browser stucked in process and in the log files:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\server.py", line 2, in 
from pydantic import BaseModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic'

this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
 <handlers>
       <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
     </handlers>
     <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\Python.exe"
arguments="<path>\server.py --port 8000"
stdoutLogEnabled="true"
stdoutLogFile="<path>\LogFiles2\python.log"
startupTimeLimit="60"
processesPerApplication="16">
       <environmentVariables>
         <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="8000" />
       </environmentVariables>
     </httpPlatform>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

server.py file starts with:

```
from typing import List, Dict, Union 
from pydantic import BaseModel
 
import uvicorn 
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, Body

from hebsafeharbor import Doc
from hsh_service import hsh_service

app = FastAPI()

class ReadyResponse(BaseModel):
service: str
status: str
```

...

(pydantic is installed, of course)

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Did you install the libraries on the server you are trying to run the app? Maybe output a pip freeze to logs before running the app.

Comment: Sounds like pydantic is not installed/not installed correctly. The directory to where Pydantic is installed needs to be on your `sys.path` list. How are you installing packages on your server?

Comment: see if this may help you https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pydantic/

Comment: It is too difficult for Python new users to understand that the packages you installed might go to a different Python release, a different user profile, or a different virtual environment, so that when IIS tries to host your web app it sees a different setup compared to what you see at command prompt. But that's what you have to learn from here.

Comment: After several attempts, I found that the necessary library folders are under `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` (anaconda). 
I assumed that it should be placed here: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages`, (Python), wich I found to be true when looking at `sys.path`. 
So I added the Anaconda3 paths with `sys.path.append` and now its femiliar.

I'm still wondering what I should have done to get them installed in the right place, because now other problems (NumPy version, for example).
I guess it's something to do with setting an environment

Comment: Your previous problem solved? Now encountering a new error?